# Chrome Extension not playing sound when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created an extension for Google Chrome. There are no errors when uploaded, and the button appears just fine on the extension bar. The extension is supposed to play a sound when clicked, but it does not. Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Extension",
    "js": ["audio.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

and here is my audio.js file:

```
var myAudio = new Audio();
myAudio.src = "audio.mp3";
myAudio.play();
```

I don't see my issue here. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

1. The toolbar button [can only have](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) an html file for the popup, there's no `"js"` parameter
2. Alternatively use a dynamically loaded event page with a click handler and omit the popup:

   manifest.json:

   ```
   "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_title": "Extension"
   },
   "background": {
       "scripts": ["event.js"],
       "persistent": false
   },
   ```

   event.js

   ```
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
       var myAudio = new Audio();
       myAudio.src = "audio.mp3";
       myAudio.play();
   });
   ```

See the [official samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:browseraction) for more examples of `browserAction` API.